# Using the open source Android HorizontalListView, unexpected results with layout_height="wrap_content"

Tags: android, listview

Using https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView

So I want to make a screen with multiple horizontal-listviews.  Here's my XML file.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#fff"
  >

  <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
  />

  <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

The only issue is when I do wrap_content for height, it registers the height as the entire screen.  I tested to make sure my second listview was there by changing the first listviews hight to a set pixel amount and both were there.

I read on the github for this that this was a known problem, but it said it was fixed... I guess I'm missing something?

If anyone has any experience with this I'd appreciate it!

Comment: do you have the project from the link on your post on github? right now is not working, and i want it. Can you post it?

Comment: I believe it was this: https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff" />

    <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if you do not get solution then replay.